# The Coinbase addresses API endpoint returns mostly empty data

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm trying to get the addresses for my Coinbase wallets.  I'm using node/axios.  I'm grabbing accounts from the "accounts" endpoint and then calling the "addresses" endpoint with each account's id field.

The js code looks like this:

```js
const getAccounts = async (auth) => {
    
    const options = {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth.access_token
        }
    };

    let response = await axios.get(
        'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts', options
    );

    
    await getWallets(auth, response.data.data);

}


const getWallets = async (auth, accounts) => {
    const options = {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth.access_token
        }
    };

    for (const account of accounts) {
        console.log(`https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/${account.id}/addresses`);
        const url = `https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/${account.id}/addresses`;
        console.log('Wallets for ' + account.name);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(url, options);
            console.log(response.data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

}
```

That results in a ton of rows that have an empty "data" array, like this:

```
Wallets for DOGE Wallet
{
  pagination: {
    ending_before: null,
    starting_after: null,
    previous_ending_before: null,
    next_starting_after: null,
    limit: 25,
    order: 'desc',
    previous_uri: null,
    next_uri: null
  },
  data: [],
  warnings: [
    {
      id: 'missing_version',
      message: 'Please supply API version (YYYY-MM-DD) as CB-VERSION header',
      url: 'https://developers.coinbase.com/api#versioning'
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems like XLM is the only account that actually comes through with data.  Any thoughts?